# HeatMap visualization

Tags: python, heatmap, seaborn

I have a dataframe  df1

```
df1.info() 


<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 38840 entries, 0 to 38839
Data columns (total 7 columns):
TIMESTAMP                 38840 non-null datetime64[ns]
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1    38696 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3    38697 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5    38695 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F6    38695 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F7    38693 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F8    38696 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(6)
memory usage: 2.1 MB
```

which looks like this :

```
 TIMESTAMP ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1 ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3 ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5 ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F6 ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F7
 ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F8
 2015-08-01 05:10:00 100 100 100 100 100 100
 2015-08-01 05:20:00 100 100 100 100 100 100
 2015-08-01 05:30:00 100 100 100 100 100 100
 2015-08-01 05:40:00 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

I try to create a heatmap with seaborn to visualize data which are between two date ( for example here between '2015-08-01 23:10:00' and '2015-08-02 02:00:00') : 
I do like this :

```
df1['TIMESTAMP']= pd.to_datetime(df_no_missing['TIMESTAMP'], '%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')
df1['date'] = df_no_missing['TIMESTAMP'].dt.date
df1['time'] = df_no_missing['TIMESTAMP'].dt.time
date_debut = pd.to_datetime('2015-08-01 23:10:00')
date_fin = pd.to_datetime('2015-08-02 02:00:00')

df1 = df1[(df1['TIMESTAMP'] >= date_debut) & (df1['TIMESTAMP'] < date_fin)]

sns.heatmap(df1.iloc[:,1:6:],annot=True, linewidths=.5)
```

I got a heatmap like in the attached

[image]

My question now is how can I replace the number in the left of the heatmap map (145...161) by their corresponding values of timestamp (2015-08-01 05:10:00, 2015-08-01 05:20:00, 2015-08-01 05:30:00, ...)

Thank you

Bests

I try to make modifications :

```
df1.set_index("TIMESTAMP", inplace=1)
sns.heatmap(df1.iloc[:, 1:6:], annot=True, linewidths=.5)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_yticklabels([i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for i in df1.TIMESTAMP], rotation=0)
```

**EDIT**

But I get error and warning :

> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:2:
> ```
>
> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>       A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>       Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> ```
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:3:
> ```
>
> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>       A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>       Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> ```
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   app.launch_new_instance()
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:4:
> ```
>
> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>       A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>       Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> ```
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>
>
>
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-129-cec498d88cac> in <module>()
>       9 
>      10 #sns.heatmap(df1.iloc[:,1:6:],annot=True, linewidths=.5)
> ---> 11 sns.heatmap(df1.iloc[:, 1:6:], annot=True, linewidths=.5)
>      12 ax = plt.gca()
>      13 ax.set_yticklabels([i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for i in df1.TIMESTAMP], rotation=0)
>
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py in
> ```
>
> heatmap(data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt, annot_kws,
>   linewidths, linecolor, cbar, cbar_kws, cbar_ax, square, ax,
>   xticklabels, yticklabels, mask, **kwargs)
>           483     plotter = _HeatMapper(data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt,
>           484                           annot_kws, cbar, cbar_kws, xticklabels,
>       --> 485                           yticklabels, mask)
>           486 
>           487     # Add the pcolormesh kwargs here
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py in
> ```
>
> **init**(self, data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt, annot_kws, cbar, cbar_kws, xticklabels, yticklabels, mask)
>           165         # Determine good default values for the colormapping
>           166         self._determine_cmap_params(plot_data, vmin, vmax,
>       --> 167                                     cmap, center, robust)
>           168 
>           169         # Sort out the annotations
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py in
> ```
>
> _determine_cmap_params(self, plot_data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust)
>           204         calc_data = plot_data.data[~np.isnan(plot_data.data)]
>           205         if vmin is None:
>       --> 206             vmin = np.percentile(calc_data, 2) if robust else calc_data.min()
>           207         if vmax is None:
>           208             vmax = np.percentile(calc_data, 98) if robust else calc_data.max()
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py
> ```
>
> in _amin(a, axis, out, keepdims)
>            27 
>            28 def _amin(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
>       ---> 29     return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
>            30 
>            31 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
>
> ```
> ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
> ```

@jeanrjc, look at the last image, there is a problem: the image is too small and there is two vertical line(scale)on the right. I hope that i'am clear now[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `TIMESTAMP` is not your index, from the `sns.heatmap` docstring:

> yticklabels : list-like, int, or bool, optional
>       If True, plot the row names of the dataframe. If False, don't plot
>       the row names. If list-like, plot these alternate labels as the
>       yticklabels. If an integer, use the index names but plot only every
>       n label.

The row names being the index.

So you can just set your index accordingly:

```
df1.set_index("TIMESTAMP", inplace=1)
```

and with your `sns` command, it will work almost fine. To problem is that you'll have an ugly representation of the date.

Alternatively, you can do, **instead of changing the index**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
...
...
ax = sns.heatmap(df1.iloc[:, 1:6:], annot=True, linewidths=.5)
ax.set_yticklabels([i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for i in df1.TIMESTAMP], rotation=0)
```

HTH

Comment: thank you for your reply. I edit my post to explain more the problem

Comment: @Bio either you do `df1.set_index("TIMESTAMP", inplace=1)` or you do the trick with `ax.set_yticklabels(...)`, not both !

Comment: @Bio Nice, don't hesitate to [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) the answer if you found it useful as well.